# Unable to Connect SQL server to Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have performed the below steps:
1- Control Panel > Administrative Tool > Click on ODBC

2- Go to User DSN and Click on Add button

3- Select the respective database (SQL Server Native Client)

4- Give the name to DSN and Save

Added the below JDBC driver through pom.xml to my project:

```js
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>6.5.2.jre9-preview</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

I then executed the below piece of simple code from eclipse:

> Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
>
> Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("wsyddbd10678,1433","Username", "Password");
>
> Statement st = conn.createStatement();
>
> String Sql ="select * from miris.dimset where setsk between 5499 and 5510";
>
> ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(Sql);
>
> while (rs.next())
>   {
>         System.out.println(rs.getString("setsk"));
>   }

But it gives me an error saying :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.
```

Please suggest..

Comment: Add this information to the main question for proper analysis

Comment: @DebanjanB: Updated my question with the details

Answer (score 0):

To acquire connection to DB You need to have some dependancies setup first, depending on what do You connect on (which DB).

> Connection string setup: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

For MSSQL:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

Here are several ways You can connect to DB:

**Simplest (direct connection)**

```
private WebDriver driver;
private Connection con = null;
private Statement stmt = null;
String dataBaseName = "testDB";
String dbDriver = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:3306/";
String user = "user";
String pass = "pass";
String Query;
ResultSet res;

public void DBConnection() throws Exception {
    try {
        Class.forName(
                "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                dbDriver + dataBaseName, user, pass);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}


@Test
public void testDB() throws Exception {
    try {
        Query = "Select * from table";
        res = stmt.executeQuery(Query);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();  //or whatever driver
        driver.get("//some URL //");
        while (res.next()) //move to the next row in result set, 
        //... do your stuff //
    }
} catch(Exception e)

{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

**or Your example (updated);**

Connection Syntax (MS-SQL Server):

> [URL] = jdbc:sqlserver://[ipAddress]:portNumber/dbName

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");      
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection([URL], userName, password);
```

or try this one:

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection([URL],userName, password);
```

and then the rest of code:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
String Sql = "query";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(Sql);

while (rs.next()) 
{
    System.out.println(rs.getString("setsk"));
}
```

**(or by my opinion best one) Hibernate**

It is little work to set it up, but when is up and running it's really satisfying how it works. Here is like tutorial about it: https://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-create-first-hibernate-application

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I tried following the approach  for my example but it still gives me an error of : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Comment: I had added the jdbc JAR file in my project and then the error message did not come. However, I am stuck with a new issue now: Actually i have permissions to access my db through windows authentication but not through sql server authentication.  I am therefore not able to login in the db through my automation code

Comment: which version of jdbc are You using? I also had issue with this with microsoft db, and it turned out, it was version related.

Comment: Also check if Your connection string is OK: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/